# How to configure Multiple admin users to multiple websites in one installation in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I want to configure multiple admin users for multiple websites in magento each with their own store features.

I have tried to create the admin user roles and new admin user with minimum or required allotted features but I didn't find any option how to define admin user website based.

Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: not sure this is on-topic here, it might be better suited to webmaster.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com. This question will probably be automatically migrated if others agree with me.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed a few times in the past, see these questions (plus the comments):

- [Running Magento for multiple clients - single Installaton vs. multiple installations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988979/running-magento-for-multiple-clients-single-installaton-vs-multiple-installati/)
- [Can one host multiple store on Magento Community Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176288/can-one-host-multiple-store-on-magento-community-edition/)
- [Multiple stores and multiple admins with different roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464333/multiple-stores-and-multiple-admins-with-different-roles/)

As stated in those questions, the idea of separating admin content so that each admin can only affect "their" store doesn't actually work the  way you'd think. For instance, what if one store owner wants to add a new attribute to products? Or subtract an attribute set? Or add new categories, change configuration data, etc etc. Magento was not built with this in mind, and I cannot imagine being able to do this in a way that is airtight (so that admins cannot affect each other). Use multiple installs for this.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

---

EDIT:

As a sidenote, this being the fourth time this question has been posted to SO, obviously there's a need here and a chance for someone to create a killer extension that others pay for. Someone take this one up and post it on Magento connect for all these poor folk. :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have this functionality with the Community Edition - time to pay Varien £10K+ for the super-duper edition ?!?

Comment: You are attempting to run an enterprise, this is a feature of the enterprise version.